# What is the hash function for a normal class and why don't dataclasses have the same hash function?

Tags: python, numpy, python-dataclasses

Following is an example where the dataclass "fails" to be hashable but the normal class does produce a hash value fine.

Why does this work given that the normal class has the `np.ndarray` as well and should be unhashable?

```
import numpy as np
from dataclasses import dataclass

class X:
    def __init__(self):
        x = np.ndarray([0,1,1,0,110]) 

@dataclass(frozen=True, eq=True)
class Y:
    name: str
    unit_price: np.ndarray 

a = X()
print(a.__hash__()) 

b = Y(10, np.array([0,1,2]))
print(b.__hash__())
```

Ouput:

```
8787234869218
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.py", line 37, in <module>
    print(b.__hash__())
  File "<string>", line 3, in __hash__
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Comment: It's `numpy.ndarray` that's not hashable.  `list` also isn't hashable, but `tuple` is.  A major consideration is whether the class is mutable.

Answer (score 2):

Because you used:

```
@dataclass(frozen=True, eq=True)
```

The rules here are described in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html):

> If `eq` and `frozen` are both true, by default `dataclass()` will generate a
> `__hash__()` method for you. If `eq` is true and `frozen` is false, `__hash__()` will be set to None, marking it unhashable (which it is, since it is mutable). If `eq` is false, `__hash__()` will be left
> untouched meaning the `__hash__()` method of the superclass will be used
> (if the superclass is `object`, this means it will fall back to id-based
> hashing).

The dataclass *generated a hash function* that is hashing based on the attributes. Of course, it doesn't actually work because you used a `numpy.ndarray`.

By default, user-defined objects inherit `object.__hash__`, which just hashes based on identity, pretty much `return id(self)` (although not exactly).

The two won't behave the same, in the first case, because you told the dataclass code generator to make an "immutable" type with a corresponding `__eq__` that is based on the attributes of the object.  The hash, of course, is consistent with the `__eq__` and is based on the values of the attributes. In the second case, the hash (and equality) is based on *the identity* of the object.

To illustrate these differences:

```
>>> from dataclasses import dataclass
>>> @dataclass(frozen=True, eq=True)
... class Point1:
...     x: int
...     y: int
...
>>> points = set()
>>> points.add(Point1(0, 0))
>>> Point1(0, 0) in points
True
```

So notice, a *different point object with the same value* was in the set.

However, here is how *identity* based hashing/equality would function:

```
>>> class Point2:
...     def __init__(self, x, y):
...         self.x = x
...         self.y = y
...
>>> p = Point2(0, 0)
>>> points = set()
>>> points.add(p)
>>> Point2(0, 0) in points
False
>>> p in points
True
```